# Best way to run python function that stays alive when parent dies

Tags: python, django, django-views, multiprocessing

I have a set of python scripts that are launched from a Django view upon POST and need to run in the background while the Django server displays the next page.

I'm currently using `multiprocessing.Process` in attempts to achieve this. My code looks something like:

**views.py**

```
from myscripts.installer import foo
a = multiprocessing.Process(target=foo, args=(bar,), kwargs={'lorem':ipsum,})
a.start()
...
return HttpResponse("Installation started...")
```

But get the following error a few lines into the script: `ValueError: I/O operation on closed file`

I'm assuming this is because the "parent" process (the Django view) exits via a `return HttpResponse` and thus it's stdin/out/err get closed and the child has nothing to write to (just a guess, I'm new to multiprocessing).

What's the best/most pythonic way to run functions from other scripts from a parent function and have them keep going after the parent dies/exits?

Comment: What are the functions doing?

Comment: They're using various modules to do things (copying over large files) on a remote machine. `pexpect` is a big part of the scripts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't say it's the *best* way, but a very common approach is to use a background task manager like [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org).  I've personally used Celery in the past and found it worked well for our needs.

Using Celery makes it very easy to turn any given function into a "background" task which can run whenever it's convenient (even on a different machine).  The major drawback (compared to what you're trying to do) is that you need to set up a whole separate service with a data store (e.g., MySQL or RabbitMQ), Celery workers, and the like.

Comment: Celery sounds interesting for the long-term, and I see that it has native django support which is a plus as well. I was, however, hoping for a more simple solution but it looks like there is none so I'll accept this.

Answer (score 0):

Starting processes based on requests directly doesn't sound like a good idea. Better create a standalone service that takes over the job of running scripts and optionally offering some sorts of result reporting.

This service usually is started in parallel with your django/httpd server but it runs fully independent. In your django code you'd then need to cummunicate to that service. There's many different ways for this: communicating directly through local ports, queues, named pipes, dbus etc. or indirectly, through a database for example - which the service would poll for changes. Only make sure that the communication channel works well with multiple parallel operations and doesn't become a bottleneck.